# AWS S3- Denying upload of non-encrypted objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I am logged-in with a non-root user to my company AWS account.

The default encryption for the S3 bucket is AWS KMS with custom ARN.

However, when I try to upload a file and choose "NONE" encryption, it fails with a FORBIDDEN error. The same file can be uploaded if I use AES-256 or AWS-KMS encryption.

As far as I know the bucket has to have a DENY policy for upload of non-encrypted objects but all I can see in the bucket-policy is a DENY policy for "aws:SecureTransport": "false", which I believe is to restrict the access from non HTTPS sources.

Can anyone explain how the upload is restricted?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of places in the AWS IAM process that can cause the deny.  It could be in the organization policy, the S3 bucket policy, the S3 ACL, IAM inline policy, an IAM group policy, etc.

There are 2 tools that can help you track down where the deny is occuring.

Start with the [Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) to check your IAM policies for the user or role. 
 And the [Policy Simulator Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)

Also, if you have [Cloudtrails](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) setup you can search the logs in [Cloudwatch Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) to see what is causing the deny.

Comment: Well since it's an organisational account, I don't have permission to check some of these things. Though the restriction is not at the S3 bucket policy or S3 ACL, at least as seen by my IAM account (might be at the root level?). Will check with the admins to check for the IAM inline and group policy.
Thanks

Comment: Then use the IAM Policy Simulator, it will tell if you are denied because of the Organization SCP (service control policy).

Comment: Also, check if S3 AWS-KMS is enabled which is server side encryption.  You can find it under the Properties tab.  This can not be by the organization so you will be able to see it in your account.  This is usually set by events and lambda.  So if it is set you can change and see if it gets changed back shortly after your change.  Check from cli "aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket BUCKET"

Comment: Thanks again but I don't think I am supposed to change that. However, what will be achieved by checking if the bucket encryption is changed back automatically after my change? Even if it happens, a default bucket encryption, IMO is only to encrypt the file with that default, in case user chooses None encryption. Please correct if my understanding is incorrect.
Also, I have requested Admin to share the root bucket policy, so that will clarify some things.